# confused of mysql like query with escape character?

Tags: mysql

I have a table there are below data

```
select * from t;
+----+----------------+
| id | a              |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | u5929u732b     |
|  2 | \u5929\u732b   |
|  3 | \\u5929\\u732b |
+----+----------------+
```

Query result use equal

```
select * from t where a = '\u5929\u732b';
+----+------------+
| id | a          |
+----+------------+
|  1 | u5929u732b |
+----+------------+

select * from t where a = '\\u5929\\u732b';
+----+--------------+
| id | a            |
+----+--------------+
|  2 | \u5929\u732b |
+----+--------------+

select * from t where a = '\\\\u5929\\\\u732b';
+----+----------------+
| id | a              |
+----+----------------+
|  3 | \\u5929\\u732b |
+----+----------------+
```

these result just as I expected so no problem, then I used like  to query the result, and in this time I'm very confused

```
# as I expected
select * from t where a like '\u5929\u732b';
+----+------------+
| id | a          |
+----+------------+
|  1 | u5929u732b |
+----+------------+

# I do not understand I think it should return result of id = 2
select * from t where a like '\\u5929\\u732b';
+----+------------+
| id | a          |
+----+------------+
|  1 | u5929u732b |
+----+------------+

# I think it should return result of id = 3
select * from t where a like '\\\\u5929\\\\u732b';
+----+--------------+
| id | a            |
+----+--------------+
|  2 | \u5929\u732b |
+----+--------------+
```

So why `like` query is different with equal query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIKE` is escaped by default with '\'. But you can change that by writing:

```
select * from t where a like '\\u5929\\u732b' ESCAPE '|'
```

Reference:

- [12.5.1 String Comparison Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `\` is an escape character in mysql. This means that the statement

`select * from t where a like '\\u5929\\u732b';`

is equivalent to

`select * from t where a like 'u5929u732b;`

so the returned answer is correct.

Your third query (`select * from t where a like '\\\\u5929\\\\u732b';`) is therefore a query asking for

`select * from t where a like '\\u5929\\u732b;'`,

and therefore is also correct and the statement you could use to get the desired result!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the wildcard characters with `like` operator

```
select * from t where a like '%5929%';
```